# merge two mp4 video as single video using ffmpeg in C# is not working

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-streaming

For the last 4 hours I've been trying to combine 2 .mp4 files into one using ffmpeg in C#.

****My code is below:****

```
   public void MergeFiles(string strFile)
    {
        string strParam;

        string Path_FFMPEG = Server.MapPath("~/Video_Clips/ffmpeg.exe");

        //Merging two videos               
        String video1 = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/fast1.mp4");
        String video2 = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/fast2.mp4");
        String file = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/input.txt");
        String strResult =   Server.MapPath("~/Videos/ConvertedFiles/Output.mp4");

        strParam = " -f concat -i " + file + " -c copy " + strResult;

        process(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
    }

   public void process(string Path_FFMPEG, string strParam)
    {
        try
        {
            Process ffmpeg = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
            ffmpeg_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo = ffmpeg_StartInfo;
            ffmpeg_StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            ffmpeg.Start();
            ffmpeg.WaitForExit(30000);
            //ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
            ffmpeg.Close();
            ffmpeg.Dispose();
            ffmpeg = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

My input.txt file is below:

## List of Files to Join (Comment)

file 'D:/Kapil_WorkSpace/ExtraProjectSource/VideoDemo/VideoDemo/Videos/fast1.mp4'

file 'D:/Kapil_WorkSpace/ExtraProjectSource/VideoDemo/VideoDemo/Videos/fast2.mp4'

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error? Paste console output of ffmpeg command. If not  available, add `-report` and paste generated .log file.

Comment: Where to add '-report'? I have no idea. Please give suggestion.Thanks

Comment: How to add -report? I don't know. Please help

Comment: Use `strParam = " -f concat -i " + file + " -c copy -report " + strResult;`

Comment: Thanks for help... I add -report as your suggestion but how to check that report or how to add this into console log?

Comment: There will be a logfile created in PWD - so check ffmpeg path, input path or output path.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. I have used ffmpeg.exe. Please give more detail how to check that

Comment: look for a filename of the form `ffmpeg-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.log`

Comment: No, I have checked but no any log file over there

Comment: Do a system-wide search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found answer for my own question.

I have used ffmpeg.exe  file and there is for 32 bit system and i am using 64 bit.
So, problem is in ffmpeg build file. I have download new 64 bit build for that.

And another issue is path of videos in input.txt file are wrong.So, made it correctly and it's work completely. But it take too much time for some video and some video is work faster. I don't know what is reason for that.

Thanks all